# MS-SQL Using TRANSACTION with an cursor and inside an stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

Can anybody tell what is wrong with this stored procedure?

I want to use a transacation within an stored procedure but if I run this procedure I get the following error message: "The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION"

I don't get it... I tried so many options with the BEGIN and COMMIT commands...

P.S. It doesn't matter what's inside the while loop, the error still raises.

Any ideas?

The Error raises if I use the query window inside SSMS.

```
USE db
GO
DECLARE @return_value int,
@str_return nvarchar(100)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[proc_xxxx]
@guid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

@str_return = @str_return OUTPUT

SELECT  @str_return as N'@str_return'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Maybe this is the reason?

```
-- Declare Cursor
DECLARE xx_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT  GUID
FROM    TABLE;

    BEGIN TRY 

    BEGIN TRAN

        OPEN xx_cursor;

        -- Run through
        FETCH NEXT FROM xx_cursor INTO @guid_xx;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN

            --DO SOMETHING

            FETCH NEXT FROM xx_cursor INTO @guid_xx;
            END;

        COMMIT TRAN

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

            ROLLBACK TRAN

        SET @str_return = 'Error'

    END CATCH

    CLOSE xx_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE xx_cursor;
```

Comment: I would focus on getting rid of the loop. Looping is horribly inefficient.

Comment: maybe there's a `COMMIT TRAN` in the `--DO SOMETHING` part of your code

Comment: The code you posted should work. I have tested it with and without error inside the while and it fine, well, as fine as a cursor for DML can be.

Comment: Well it works if I fire the procedure from my application. The issue seems to be if I run the procedure inside the query window in SSMS.

Comment: I think you need to share your procedure code. And seriously....get rid of that cursor.

Comment: I have a lot of functions which are checking my rows which I want to insert/update against a lot of error-cases. So I think it would be a mess to transfer the whole code into while loops etc.
I don't have a lot of rows within these transactions (<1000) so I think it isn't a big performance issue. But thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Or what is the best replacement for cursors instead of while loops?